# Grant domain user/group privilege to folders recursively

Tags: powershell

Written below code to grant domain user privilege to folder in windows 2016. In output I can see that the user is added in folder permissions but did not add any permission though I mentioned to give full control access.

```
$rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\group","FullControl","Allow")

foreach ($file in $(Get-ChildItem "G:\usr" -recurse)) 
{
  $acl=get-acl $file.FullName

  $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

  set-acl $File.Fullname $acl
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For recursive permissions you need to set `ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit`

Here is an example (Note it's not my code):

```
$Path = "C:\temp\New folder"
$Acl = (Get-Item $Path).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Username = "Domain\User"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username, 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
```

For more details take a look at http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-manage-file-system-acl,2-837.html

Comment: Code is updated as mentioned above. Now it is updating the permission but throwing below exception as well.


Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "No flags can be set.
Parameter name: inheritanceFlags"
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1:7 char:3
+   $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "No flags can be set.